# Can you ever view your private keys on the TREZOR?

Tags: private-key-export, trezor

ON a TREZOR, is there a way to see the private key after it has been generated from the seed?  One that you could then import into another wallet manually.  I don't know that I would ever want to do that but I am just curious..

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can as the Trezor (and every other hardware wallet) does not expose your private keys to the computer it is connected to. This is how you can still securely spend your Bitcoin even with a computer that has malware on it.

However, the Trezor 24 word seed uses BIP 39 and BIP 32 so you can use that to derive your private keys on another machine.

Answer (score 2):

Generating, and thus exposing, the private key using the seed words would be very foolish. It would be the same as not using a TREZOR at all. You NEVER want the private keys be other than safely within your TREZOR. The generated seed words should never be entered on a (connected) computer or device, just keep them safe off line. There are a number of wallets you can use to access your coins by connecting your TREZOR. You can use the XPUB address to monitor addresses with other software. See the FAQ and manual on the TREZOR website.

Comment: When somebody sends bch to yous trezor btc address, exporting private key for single address would make recovering coins easier